# Comparing Accuracy of different classification models in ML

Tags: python, pandas, svm, logistic-regression

I am working on a project to test my skills on Classification models but seems like I made a error and am not sure how to solve it. Below is my code and error:

Required: Implement different algorithms like decision trees, logistic regression, and svm to see which gives better accuracy. Compare the results of each algorithm and understand the behavior of models.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics

def main():
    x, y = loadData()
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = trainTest(x,y)
    logisticAccuracy = logisticRegressionModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
    dectreeAccuracy = decisionTreeModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
    svmAccuracy = svmModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
    printComparisonResults(logisticAccuracy,dectreeAccuracy,svmAccuracy)

def loadData():
    df = pd.read_csv('D:\Tutorials\Resources\creditcard.csv')
    x = df[['Time','V1','V2','V3','V5','V6','V7','V8','V9','V10','V11','V12',\
    'V13','V14','V5','V16','V17','V18','V19','V20','V21','V22','V23',\
    'V24','V25','V26','V27', 'V28','Amount']]
    y = df['Class']

    return x, y

def trainTest(x,y):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
    return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test

# LogisticRegression model
def logisticRegressionModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    logistic_reg = LogisticRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = logistic_reg.predict(x_test)

    #evaluate accuracy of our model
    acc = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    return acc

def decisionTreeModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    dec_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    dec_tree = dec_tree.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = dec_tree.predict(x_test)

    #evaluate model
    acc = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    return acc

def svmModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    svm_model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
    svm_model = svm_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = svm_model.predict(y_test)

    #evaluate model
    acc = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    return acc

def printComparisonResults(logisticAccuracy,dectreeAccuracy,svmAccuracy):
    print("Printing Results")

    lr = "Logistic Regression"
    dt = "Decision Tree"
    sv = "SVM is Accurate"

    if logisticAccuracy > (dectreeAccuracy and svmAccuracy):
        print(lr, "is accurate than", dt, "and", sv)
    elif dectreeAccuracy > (logisticAccuracy and svmAccuracy):
        print(dt, "is accurate than", lr, "and", sv)
    else:
        print(sv, "is accurate than", lr, "and", dt)

    print("Done")

if name == 'main': main()
```

The error I am getting:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I have reshaped my array to `x = np.array(df[[...]].reshape((1,-1))` but still getting an error:

```
raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 2470]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! There are several changes you need to consider.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics
import sys

def main():
    x, y = loadData()
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = trainTest(x,y)
    logisticAccuracy = logisticRegressionModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
    dectreeAccuracy = decisionTreeModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
    svmAccuracy = svmModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
    printComparisonResults(logisticAccuracy,dectreeAccuracy,svmAccuracy)

def loadData():
    df = pd.read_csv('.\creditcard.csv')
    x = df[['Time','V1','V2','V3','V5','V6','V7','V8','V9','V10','V11','V12',\
    'V13','V14','V5','V16','V17','V18','V19','V20','V21','V22','V23',\
    'V24','V25','V26','V27', 'V28','Amount']].values
    y = df['Class'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    return x, y

def trainTest(x,y):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25, random_state=0, stratify=y)
    return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test

# LogisticRegression model
def logisticRegressionModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    logistic_reg = LogisticRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = logistic_reg.predict(x_test)

    #evaluate accuracy of our model
    acc = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    return acc
def decisionTreeModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    dec_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    dec_tree = dec_tree.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = dec_tree.predict(x_test)

    #evaluate model
    acc = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    return acc
def svmModel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    svm_model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
    svm_model = svm_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = svm_model.predict(x_test)

    #evaluate model
    acc = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    return acc
def printComparisonResults(logisticAccuracy,dectreeAccuracy,svmAccuracy):
    print("Printing Results")

    lr = "Logistic Regression"
    dt = "Decision Tree"
    sv = "SVM is Accurate"

    if logisticAccuracy > (dectreeAccuracy and svmAccuracy):
        print(lr, "is accurate than", dt, "and", sv)
    elif dectreeAccuracy > (logisticAccuracy and svmAccuracy):
        print(dt, "is accurate than", lr, "and", sv)
    else:
        print(sv, "is accurate than", lr, "and", dt)

    print("Done")
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

output:

```
Printing Results
Logistic Regression is accurate than Decision Tree and SVM is Accurate
Done
```

And your implementation would work perfectly :), I used the data which is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/xgboost-smote-detect-fraud/master/data/creditcard.csv).

Comment: Thanks, though it seems not to work at my end...this is the error after considering changes  raise ValueError("X.shape[1] = %d should be equal to %d, "

ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 29, the number of features at training time

Comment: The error is due to passing `y_test` (instead of `x_test`) for predict in `svmModel` function! @Charles